# how to display total no of rows in footer in a table in obiee 11g dynamically?

Tags: obiee

In obiee 11g in the dashboard for a particular table we can set number of rows to be displayed per page but how we can show dynamically total no of rows in a table instead of all rows below the table?

Comment: Have you tried this: `MAX(RCOUNT("Insert OBIEE Column Here from Report"))` in the formula for a column? What have you tried? You can put that derived column in its own table shown above the analysis, so you can instantly see the number of rows returned for the table that is below it.

Comment: I have to show dynamically total no of rows count in the dashboard for a table.

Comment: How does this requirement you have stated differ from the functionality of a column formula that is initiated at run time? What have you tried?

Comment: Suppose in a table we have four columns having 150 rows of data. In pagination section I have declared 25 rows to display per page. Now I have to show total number of rows below the table instead of (1-25) rows.

Comment: Each column has 150 rows, and you have 4 columns... so would you want to show 600 (150 * 4) or would you want to show 150? Does it have to be beside the pagination section? If so, the only thing I can think of off the top of my head is some custom javascript that you can insert there... but I'm not sure if it will even let you do that.

Comment: I would like to show 150 on the button of each page beside (1-25).